# sparql queries in project

Tags: spring-boot, sparql

I have start working on project using SPARQL and springboot. How to managing very large SPARSQL queries? What is the right place to implement them in project? Currently I am just using methods with Springbuilder and returned a query as a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing your queries as a String is fine, as long as you are *very* careful when injecting any user-provided input into your query.

A safer approach is to use a query builder, such as the [RDF4J SparqlBuilder](http://docs.rdf4j.org/sparqlbuilder/), so you can construct your queries in a fluent API, e.g. like this:

```java
// SELECT ?product where { ?product a ex:book }   
selectQuery.prefix(ex).select(product).where(product.isA(ex.iri("book"));
```

As for where to manage this stuff in your project, it depends a bit of the APIs you're using, but assuming you're using [RDF4J](http://docs.rdf4j.org/programming/), for example, I would typically recommend some variation of a [DAO pattern](http://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern), and creating your DAO class by means of a [repository (connection) wrapper](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/eclipse/rdf4j/repository/base/RepositoryWrapper.html) object.